# func Encode(), encoding all part of xml

Tags: xml, string, go, marshalling

This is code :

```
import (
"bytes"
"encoding/xml"
"fmt")

func main() {
type body struct {
    Message string `xml:"message"`
}
myXml := body{
    Message:"This is <myText>",
}

    w := &bytes.Buffer{}
        enc := xml.NewEncoder(w)
        enc.Indent("", "  ")
        if err := enc.Encode(myXml); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        request := w.String()
        fmt.Println(request)
    }
```

Is there any way that the value of field message do not encode.I want  not encode.
This is result :

```
<body>
  <message>This is &lt;myText&gt;</message>
</body>
```

Comment: `Encode()` is to encode some Go value into XML. You already have an XML, that's why encoding it (again) will apply escaping. If you don't want that, just write your source to the output as-is.

Comment: Sorry . I edited .

Comment: Are you wanting the encoder to ignore the `Message` field completely? If so, use `\`xml:"-"\`` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mission of [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) is to produce *valid* XML documents. Escaping the `<` and `>` characters is a must for a valid XML. Don't worry, the content of `<message>` will be `This is <myText>`, but this text must appear as `This is &lt;myText&gt;` in the source of XML.

Note that using the `xml:",innerxml"` tag value you could force outputting raw XML data as documented at [`xml.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal):

> ```
> - a field with tag ",innerxml" is written verbatim, not subject
>   to the usual marshaling procedure.
> ```

Like this:

```
type rawxml struct {
    Data string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
type body struct {
    Message rawxml `xml:"message"`
}
myXml := body{
    Message: rawxml{"This is <myText>"},
}
```

This would output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZD8aUdZfcDO)):

```
<body>
  <message>This is <myText></message>
</body>
```

Or implementing and using custom [`xml.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler), but again, **this is invalid XML**, this is not what you want. What you have right now is exactly what you want.